# How can I extract the same employeeID attribute value that Outlook is displaying?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, active-directory, outlook, ldap

Our company uses ActiveDirectory for various reasons. One of them is to handle Outlook contacts and user log-in IDs.

I have written a program to detect the logged in user id, and to search the Active Directory using the extracted login id. The pulled information from the Active Directory is then stored in a database.

Here is the code I used to pull ActiveDirectory information data:

```
Dim enTry As DirectoryEntry = _
     New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://myCOMPANY/DC=myCOMPANY,DC=myCOMPANY,DC=com")

Dim mySearcher As DirectorySearcher = New DirectorySearcher(enTry)
mySearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(anr=" & thisUser & "))" 
'thisUser is the variable holding the Windows ID that is accessing the ASPX page


mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("employeeID")   'just in case I need to do this.

Dim resEnt As SearchResult

Try
  For Each resEnt In mySearcher.FindAll()

  Dim fullname As String = resEnt.GetDirectoryEntry.Properties.Item("cn").Value
  'fullname will always pull the right information

  Dim e_id As String = resEnt.GetDirectoryEntry.Properties.Item("employeeID").Value
  'e_id will sometimes be NOTHING, sometimes will contain an ID that
  '   is different from the one displayed in Outlook Contact Information
  '   and sometimes it will be matching the employeeID listed in Outlook info

Catch ex as Exception
  Log("Failed to pull AD data: " & ex.Message)
End Try
```

For some reason, some users have no values for their employeeID field, and some have.

However, all of the users, will display an employeeID value when browsed in Outlook.

I designed the following image to help you understand what I am going through. 
The image is divided into two sections, a section for each CASE.

========================================================

**In Case 1**, the employee has logged in to Windows using his ID: `xms33808`

Outlook shows that his Employee ID is `16078`

Outlook shows that his email alias is `xms33808`

ASP.Net command window shows that his employeeID is `xms33808`, which is not true

======================================================

=======================================================

**In Case 2**, the employee has logged in to Windows using ID: `25163`

Outlook shows that his Employee ID is `25163`

Outlook shows that his email alias is `MutawaAAB`

ASP.Net command windows shows that his employeeID is `NOTHING`.

=======================================================

My question is : How can I extract the same employeeID value information that Outlook is displaying?

[image: Case 1: employeeID is different from ASP.Net than Outlook]
[image: Case 2: employeeID is found in Outlook, but Nothing in ASP.Net]

Comment: Very odd - you dont have a secondary AD server do you?

Comment: @DarkcatStudios No. Only one AD server. But how can I check if there IS an other one? I mean without going through IT human intervention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the attribute that is holding the employee ID.

For those looking for an answer to the same question, here is the name of the attribute:

`extensionattribute2`

The way I came across this is by printing out all attribute values held by the search entry result..

```
For Each resEnt In mySearcher.FindAll()
    Debug.Print("The properties of the " + resEnt.GetDirectoryEntry().Name + " are :")
        For Each singleAttribute As String In DirectCast(resEnt.Properties, ResultPropertyCollection).PropertyNames
            Debug.Print(singleAttribute & Convert.ToString(" = "))
            For Each singleValue As [Object] In DirectCast(resEnt.Properties, ResultPropertyCollection)(singleAttribute)
                Debug.Print(vbTab + singleValue.ToString)
            Next
        Next
Next
```

Then I examined the output and found the badge number printed out next to `extensionattribute2` ..

Very strange name for a property that should be called `employeeID` or `staffID` or `BadgeNumber` or anything else that makes sense.

Later on, I modified my code that searches the Active Directory to search not only by the Sama Account, but also by this `extensionattribute2` thing too since each employee has a unique ID.

```
Dim LookFor As String = "25163"
Dim mySearcher As DirectorySearcher = New DirectorySearcher(enTry)

mySearcher.Filter = "(&(| (anr=" & LookFor & ")" & _ 
                         "(extensionattribute2=" & LookFor & "))" & _ 
                         "(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=user))"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use .net 3.5 or above you can use the following which is much easier than LDAP etc...

Add a reference and an Imports statement for `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`

To get details for a specific user:

```
Dim objPC As PrincipalContext = Nothing 
Dim objADUser As UserPrincipal = Nothing
Try 
    objPC = New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "YourDomain")
    objADUser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(objPC, "NetworkLogin") 
Catch ex As Exception 
End Try
```

To get details for the currently logged on user

```
Dim objADUser As UserPrincipal = Nothing
Try
    objADUser = UserPrincipal.Current
Catch ex As Exception
End Try
```

You can then interrogate the object objADUser and get all sorts of details such as

```
objADUser.VoiceTelephoneNumber
objADUser.EmailAddress
objADUser.EmployeeNumber and many others.....
```

Comment: As Bo TX mentions below... you should use employeeNumber and not employeeID whichever way you choose to find the details from AD.

Comment: `objADUser.EmployeeNumber` caused the code editor to generate an error since `EmployeeNumber` is not a valid attribute or member/property of `objADUser`. However, `EmployeeId` is.

Answer (score 1):

There is a confusingly similar AD Attribute called 'employeeNumber'. Could it be that Outlook is actually using this property to populate it's display?

Per this Microsoft Support page on Outlook Contact Cards, 'employeeID' is not a field that you can use. However, 'employeeNumber' is.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/981022

Hope this helps at least advance your troubleshooting efforts.

Comment: I tried to examine the content of `resEnt.GetDirectoryEntry.Properties.Item("employeeNumber").Value` but it is Nothing for both cases

Comment: It sounds like you may need to coordinate with your Exchange Administrator. They should be able to confirm where and how this field is being pulled for display.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to connect to exchange server and query for the required data,and then parse the information required from the xml.

Comment: How can I view the XML response from AD server?

Comment: The AD server will not give u xml.The xml is response of the request made to the Exchange Server.This way it becomes more secured,instead parsing data from the AD.